# Anyone knows if is possible to upload an Flet App in Azure?

Tags: python, azure, pycharm, flet

I have the to_Do_app model that the Flet documentation gives, and i am trying to learn how upload it to an azure server in a way to learn how Azure works. But investigating there is not clear information about it. I'll be grateful if someone teach me if is it possible and how.

The only thing i found is this [text](https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/deploying-web-app/hosting-providers)but im still not sure if the framework its not compatible with Azure for now.

This is the code that i want to upload.

https://github.com/flet-dev/examples/tree/5c16ccc21c41c3acf9221dec8bac5127a3871b4f/python/apps/todo

Comment: can you provide more details, such as the Python version and the code you have tried?

Comment: Sure, i ll share the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the sample code and successfully deployed it to the Azure app service.

I ran the commands below for the virtual environment:

`python -m venv venv`

`.\venv\Scripts\activate`.

**requirements.txt**:

```json
flet  ==  0.19.0
```

I added this `flet.app(target=main, view=flet.AppView.WEB_BROWSER)` to the end of main.py for deployment as a web app.

**main. py**:

```py
import flet
from flet import (
    Checkbox,
    Column,
    FloatingActionButton,
    IconButton,
    Page,
    Row,
    Tab,
    Tabs,
    TextField,
    UserControl,
    colors,
    icons,
)
class Task(UserControl):
    def __init__(self, task_name, task_status_change, task_delete):
        super().__init__()
        self.completed = False
        self.task_name = task_name
        self.task_status_change = task_status_change
        self.task_delete = task_delete
    def build(self):
        self.display_task = Checkbox(
            value=False, label=self.task_name, on_change=self.status_changed
        )
        self.edit_name = TextField(expand=1)

        self.display_view = Row(
            alignment="spaceBetween",
            vertical_alignment="center",
            controls=[
                self.display_task,
                Row(
                    spacing=0,
                    controls=[
                        IconButton(
                            icon=icons.CREATE_OUTLINED,
                            tooltip="Edit To-Do",
                            on_click=self.edit_clicked,
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            icons.DELETE_OUTLINE,
                            tooltip="Delete To-Do",
                            on_click=self.delete_clicked,
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            ],
        )
        self.edit_view = Row(
            visible=False,
            alignment="spaceBetween",
            vertical_alignment="center",
            controls=[
                self.edit_name,
                IconButton(
                    icon=icons.DONE_OUTLINE_OUTLINED,
                    icon_color=colors.GREEN,
                    tooltip="Update To-Do",
                    on_click=self.save_clicked,
                ),
            ],
        )
        return Column(controls=[self.display_view, self.edit_view])

    def edit_clicked(self, e):
        self.edit_name.value = self.display_task.label
        self.display_view.visible = False
        self.edit_view.visible = True
        self.update()
    def save_clicked(self, e):
        self.display_task.label = self.edit_name.value
        self.display_view.visible = True
        self.edit_view.visible = False
        self.update()
    def status_changed(self, e):
        self.completed = self.display_task.value
        self.task_status_change(self)
    def delete_clicked(self, e):
        self.task_delete(self)
class TodoApp(UserControl):
    def build(self):
        self.new_task = TextField(hint_text="Whats needs to be done?", expand=True)
        self.tasks = Column()
        self.filter = Tabs(
            selected_index=0,
            on_change=self.tabs_changed,
            tabs=[Tab(text="all"), Tab(text="active"), Tab(text="completed")],
        )
        # application's root control (i.e. "view") containing all other controls
        return Column(
            width=600,
            controls=[
                Row(
                    controls=[
                        self.new_task,
                        FloatingActionButton(icon=icons.ADD, on_click=self.add_clicked),
                    ],
                ),
                Column(
                    spacing=25,
                    controls=[
                        self.filter,
                        self.tasks,
                    ],
                ),
            ],
        )
    def add_clicked(self, e):
        task = Task(self.new_task.value, self.task_status_change, self.task_delete)
        self.tasks.controls.append(task)
        self.new_task.value = ""
        self.update()
    def task_status_change(self, task):
        self.update()
    def task_delete(self, task):
        self.tasks.controls.remove(task)
        self.update()
    def update(self):
        status = self.filter.tabs[self.filter.selected_index].text
        for task in self.tasks.controls:
            task.visible = (
                status == "all"
                or (status == "active" and task.completed == False)
                or (status == "completed" and task.completed)
            )
        super().update()
    def tabs_changed(self, e):
        self.update()
def main(page: Page):
    page.title = "ToDo App"
    page.horizontal_alignment = "center"
    page.update()
       app = TodoApp()
       page.add(app)
flet.app(target=main, view=flet.AppView.WEB_BROWSER)
```

I ran the command below:

`python main.py`

**Local Output**:

[image]

I ran the command below to generate a "dist" folder for deployment purposes.

`flet publish main.py`

I created an Azure web app in the Azure portal, selected the runtime stack as Node 18, and chose the operating system as Windows, as shown below.

[image]

I deployed a web app to Azure App Service through VS Code, as shown below.

[image]

**Azure App Service Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, now im doing it.  And later imma share how it went.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the guide. I tried your method and got further than I have before. I have managed to deploy my app to azure from VS Code, but when I go to the URL to view the app, I just get the spinning flet loading icon.

Any ideas what I've missed?

Thanks